# Gatling with Karate (Maven project): I'm trying to setup Gatling in my existing karate project but during build it is failing as follows

Tags: karate

Following failure is seen:

15:11:32.152 [main] ERROR io.gatling.app.Gatling$ - Run crashed
*java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
at* com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateProtocol$$anon$1.newComponents(KarateProtocol.scala:34)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.$anonfun$components$1(Protocol.scala:68)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:434)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.componentsFactory$1(Protocol.scala:68)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.comps$1(Protocol.scala:71)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.$anonfun$components$4(Protocol.scala:73)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:434)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.components(Protocol.scala:73)
at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateActionBuilder.build(KarateActionBuilder.scala:9)
at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.$anonfun$build$1(BuildAction.scala:28)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft(LinearSeq.scala:169)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft$(LinearSeq.scala:165)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:79)
at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build(BuildAction.scala:27)
at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build$(BuildAction.scala:26)
at io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:51)
at io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder.build(PopulationBuilder.scala:100)
at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.buildScenario(Simulation.scala:170)
at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.$anonfun$scenarios$1(Simulation.scala:174)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:219)
at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.scenarios(Simulation.scala:174)
at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:82)
at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:52)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:80)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:45)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:37)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:53)
at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Serializable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 45 common frames omitted
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:53)
at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateProtocol$$anon$1.newComponents(KarateProtocol.scala:34)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.$anonfun$components$1(Protocol.scala:68)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:434)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.componentsFactory$1(Protocol.scala:68)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.comps$1(Protocol.scala:71)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.$anonfun$components$4(Protocol.scala:73)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:434)
at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.components(Protocol.scala:73)
at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateActionBuilder.build(KarateActionBuilder.scala:9)
at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.$anonfun$build$1(BuildAction.scala:28)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft(LinearSeq.scala:169)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft$(LinearSeq.scala:165)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:79)
at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build(BuildAction.scala:27)
at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build$(BuildAction.scala:26)
at io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:51)
at io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder.build(PopulationBuilder.scala:100)
at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.buildScenario(Simulation.scala:170)
at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.$anonfun$scenarios$1(Simulation.scala:174)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:219)
at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.scenarios(Simulation.scala:174)
at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:82)
at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:52)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:80)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:45)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:37)
at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Serializable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 45 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue